# Can I configure an nginx reverse proxy to not modify specific requests?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

For the default server case can the reverse proxy just to send the request to the original intended location?

essentially just letting certain requests "pass thru"

I tried something like this but it did not work

```
   location / {
       proxy_pass $request_uri
   }
```

Comment: Your example is missing a scheme and an upstream server name. What is behind the reverse proxy?

Comment: what is being modified that you don't want to be?